# Qt notification example error

Tags: qt

I am working on Qt application on Ubuntu 10.04 with 'Qt Creator' and trying to run the example application given in the toolkit,

It is giving me an error, when i run the application.

```
notificationexample.cpp:34: error: ovinotificationinterface.h: No such file or directory
```

Please help

Comment: "run the application"? you mean compile ;-) The compiler can't find the header file. Did you have `CONFIG += ovinotifications` in your qmake file? Have you tried `#include <ovinotifications/ovinotificationinterface.h`?

Comment: I have checked for the file, but it is not present in the directory :(

Answer (score 0):

ovinotificationinterface.h is part of the mobile/embedded code rather than the desktop pcakage, how did you get Qt Creator installed? Or if you want to use the mobile stuff double check it's been installed.